# Help with maximization problem

Tags: calculus

In a book I'm reading, a claim is made that

$f(a) = r \cos(a) - m \sin(a)$

has the maximum

$\sqrt{r^2+m^2}$

(where a, r and m are real numbers).

But I'm not sure how to prove it or even if it's true.
Setting $\dfrac{d}{da} f(a) = 0 $ gives $-r \sin(a) - m \cos(a)=0$ or $\tan(a)=-m/r$, so $a=\arctan(-m/r)$. [Plugging that in](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%2acos%28arctan%28-m%2Fr%29%29+-+m%2asin%28arctan%28-m%2Fr%29%29) into wolfram does not give the claimed result...

Comment: Fixing the W|A input gives the correct result (after modifications): [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r*cos+arctan+%28-m%2Fr%29+++-+m*sin+arctan+%28-m%2Fr++%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(a) = r \cos(a) - m \sin(a) = \sqrt{r^2+m^2}(\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+m^2}} \cos a - \frac{m}{\sqrt{r^2+m^2}} \cos a)$.

Now suppose $\cos \theta = \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+m^2}}$, $\sin \theta = \frac{m}{\sqrt{r^2+m^2}}$, then you have $f(a) = \sqrt{r^2+m^2} \cos (a+\theta)$, from which the maximum and minimum values are obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $r\cos a - m \sin a= \sqrt{r^2+m^2}\left(\dfrac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+m^2}}\cos a - \dfrac{m}{\sqrt{r^2+m^2}} \sin a\right)$ and there exists $b$ with $\sin b=\dfrac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+m^2}}$ and $\cos b=\dfrac{m}{\sqrt{r^2+m^2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

From your link,

$$\frac{m^2}{r\sqrt{\frac{m^2}{r^2}+1}}+\frac r{\sqrt{\frac{m^2}{r^2}+1}}$$

$$=\frac{m^2}{\sqrt{m^2+r^2}}+\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{m^2+r^2}}$$

$$=\frac{m^2+r^2}{\sqrt{m^2+r^2}}=\sqrt{m^2+r^2}$$